# Префикс задания литералу кодировки utf-8 в MinGW

Tags: c, utf-8, c99, c11

Столкнулся со следующей ситуацией.

Имеется функция `SDL_CreateWindow()`, которая первым параметром принимает указатель на строку в кодировке `utf-8`.

Для проекта задана опция компиляции:

```
-fexec-charset=cp1251
```

Понятное дело, что если не указано иное, то строковые литералы *зашиваются* в `exe` в кодировке `cp1251`.

Для персонального перевода строкового литерала в кодировку `utf-8` я сделал так:

```
SDL_CreateWindow(u8"Заголовок в utf-8", ...);
```

Проблема в том, что если в настройках компиляции явно не задан используемый стандарт `C`, то компиляция проходит успешно, а строковой литерал попадает в `exe` в формате `utf-8`, но если в настройках компиляции явно указать стандарт языка `C99`, то компилятор не понимает, что значит `u8`.

Разве префикс `u8` появился только в `C11`? 
Где об этом говорится в стандарте?
И какой стандарт `C` использует компилятор `MinGW32`, если он не указан явно?

Comment: Да, `u8` [появился](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/string_literal) в C11. *"какой стандарт C использует компилятор MinGW32, если он не указан явно"* Зависит от версии компилятора. Вывод `gcc --version` в студию.

Comment: `C:\Users\nb529>"C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin\mingw32-gcc.exe" --version` выводит
`mingw32-gcc.exe (tdm-1) 5.1.0`

Comment: Читайте иногда доки к своему компилятору: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.1.0/gcc/Standards.html#Standards *The default, if no C language dialect options are given, is `-std=gnu11`*

Comment: @zed, спасибо за помощь. Доки читаю редко, потому что пользуюсь десятком компиляторов.

Comment: @MGNeo Не в тему, но GCC 5.1 уже больше четырех лет. Я бы советовал поставить последний MinGW-w64, там уже GCC 8.1 есть.

Comment: Есть и MinGW32, и MinGW-w64 x32/x64 различных версий, и MSVC, и Clang. Проектов много, каждый из них заточен под свое окружение. Есть даже такие проекты, которые работают под досом и собираются шестым борландом.